# How to Export current Collection WITS to create new Process config template

Tags: tfs-2015

We have been using TFS2015  over the last 14 months and during that time we have modified various WITS as well as the categories.xml and process configuration.xml files.

How would I export the current WITS and related files to create and updated Process template that we can use when creating new Projects, or even move to our test Environments.

At this point any new projects need to be modified to add all the changes that were made over the last 14 months.

Answer (score 0):

Use `witadmin.exe`'s `export*` commands to export each of the elements that make up the process template.

Use the [Process Template Manager in Visual Studio to download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates) the base template as a ZIP file.

Extract the zip file and overwrite the files in the zip with the ones you've individually exported.

Then update the main process template XML file and update the template GUID with a new one (or else TFS will block the import of the new Process Template).

Finally, use the Visual Studio Process Template manager to upload the modified template back to TFS.

[The TFS Team Project Manager](https://github.com/jelledruyts/TfsTeamProjectManager) provides all kinds of nice features to simplify the process of importing/exporting/comparing process templates.